# UIWebview works slow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

UIWebview load the content very slow.

```
WebView=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
WebView.delegate=self;
[WebView addSubview:spinner];
[self.view addSubview:WebView];
NSString *decodeString=[@"www.google.com" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[WebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:decodeString]]];
```

What i did wrong?

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Arunkumar.P

Answer (score 0):

Last two lines should be:

```
[WebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]]];
```

Your webview isn't loading "slow" at the moment; implement the error delegate method and you'll see what's really happening.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having it in two lines like he did and it has nothing to do with the problems he's having.
I'm having some issues with very slow loading as well but have no idea why its happening cause URLs loaded outside the webview is fast.

Comment: The last two lines of his code have everything to do with the problem. A) `@"www.google.com"` is not a URL the web view can load, and B) adding percent escapes in this example does nothing.